# jQuery live change on checkbox IE8

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events

I have a couple of checkboxes loaded in with Ajax (because of database data),
Now I want to do some actions when these checkboxes changes from unchecked to checked and vice versa.

I am also using this for my checkbox:
http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

this is my checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boats" class="boatID-2 afvaartijdID-3 boats" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
```

I have tried live change function and on change function but both wont work in IE8.
Like this

```
$(document).on('change','.boats',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

and

```
$('.boats').live('change',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

I have the latest version of jQuery.
Anybody any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just one thing: the ID must be unique, so in your case it should be `id="boatID-2"`.

Comment: I [made a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CReam/) from your code. It works fine for me. Please create a fiddle with your exact code and tell us what is your problem.

Comment: You are saying this does not work on new elements in IE8? http://jsfiddle.net/CReam/1/

Comment: yes, I load the checkbox in, so it doesnt exist yet. I want to use the change function on new loaded checkbox, and since their is a layer on top of it click functions wont work. its weird cause your example does work in IE8, i think something is bugging with the function..

Comment: ok, got it working.. because of the jquery checkbox i use ie8 doesnt find the change but I could use a check and uncheck event to trigger change.. so i got it working thanks all for your ideas/help

Comment: @Peter You should write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addon I used for my checkbox

This one: http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Was bugging in IE8 with the change event.

I couldnt use the live or on function to get change working, but the plugin had a couple of method to trigger change.
You where able to use the check and uncheck event to trigger change event.

So that solved the problem.

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".boats").live("click", function(){
   // do stuff
})
```

In newer version of jQuery its recommeded to use on() and off() instead of live() / die()

```
$(document).on("click", ".boats", function(){
   // do stuff
})
```

Comment: better is using `.on()`, because `.live()` is depercated

Comment: @bazmegakapa - can you explain your comment in detail please? Do you mean they are not "change" events or do you imply they differ from each other (which to me they do not)